# Any non wavecrest issuer euro zone debit cards?

Tags: debitcard, bitcoin-credit-card, point-of-sale

After the recent disruption to all debit cards that were using the wavecrest card issuer, it appears they were by far the most common issuer for bitcoin debit card companies. Most of them have stated that they are working on replacements. I notice that bitpay's card uses a different one and is US only.

Is anyone aware of any that are live already with another card issuer in euro zone?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this one
Low fees, they accept BTC, BCH, ETH, LTC and BTG
Also, they have very cool app for iOS & Android

https://cryptoanteg.com/blogs/reviews/epayments-your-new-crypto-currency-debit-mastercard

Comment: Seems great, but haven't figured out what the they mean by "Cryptocurrencies (BTC, LTC, ETH, BCH, BTG) - at the rate of ePayments at the time of withdrawal;" in the deposit fees section